# Getting JavaScript to create a full li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function loadFamily() {

  var family = ["Kelly", "Paul", "Jason", "Jessica", "Mat"];
  var ulElement = document.getElementById("nameList");

  for (var name in family); 
  {
    var listItem = ulElement.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
    listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(family[name]));
  }

}
```

I am trying to get this code to create a ul in my html. I have been able to make it work; however it will only place the last name of the array when the page is loaded. This is my first time working with JavaScript and I'm sure that this is a really simple problem, but any help is much appreciated!

Comment: as a side note, `for/in` on an array can bite you - just beware

Comment: Arrays have a handy forEach() method for iterating over themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stopping your `for` loop here:

```
for (var name in family); 
//----------------------^ Remove this.
```

It runs fully and the index is in the last, so it executes only the last one now. So change your code to:

```
function loadFamily() {

  var family = ["Kelly", "Paul", "Jason", "Jessica", "Mat"];
  var ulElement = document.getElementById("nameList");

  for (var name in family) {
    var listItem = ulElement.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
    listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(family[name]));
  }

}
```

***Note:*** A `for...in` loop only iterates over enumerable properties. Do not use this for Arrays. It is better to change your loop like:

```js
function loadFamily() {

  var family = ["Kelly", "Paul", "Jason", "Jessica", "Mat"];
  var ulElement = document.getElementById("nameList");

  for (var name = 0; name < family.length; name++) {
    var listItem = ulElement.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
    listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(family[name]));
  }

}
```

The above is better and good.

Answer (score 2):

The is more of a note than the answer as the other person answered you.  But arrays have a `forEach()` can use for iteration.

```
var family = ["Kelly", "Paul", "Jason", "Jessica", "Mat"];

function loadFamily() {
    var ulElement = document.getElementById("nameList");

    family.forEach(function(name){
        var listItem = ulElement.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
        listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    });
}
```

You also have jquery in your tags but none of this is jquery.  But, just in case you were curious how you could do the same with jquery.

```
var family = ["Kelly", "Paul", "Jason", "Jessica", "Mat"];

function loadFamily() {
    $('#nameList').append($.map(family, function(name){
        return $('<li>').text(name);
    }));
}
```

Comment: That is very helpful, Thank you. I am just getting into and learning JavaScript and jQuery. I have only really used it in small samples for rollovers and some img manipulation